# Databinding WPF C# WPF to labels in Codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, list, data-binding

I have a list of Accounts with some properties which are saved in a database.

On my Window I´m going to show the Username from the Account list

```
for (int i = 0; i < liste.Count; i++)
{
    Label l = new Label();
    l.Height = 30;

    l.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    l.Content = liste[i].Username + "\n";
    l.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Selectuser);
    l.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    stack.Children.Add(l); // stackpanel in the xaml
    SetKnownImageAcc(Convert.ToInt32( liste[i].AccAId)); // add a picture near the username
}
```

So I have now I MouseButton Event on every label I created but when I click on one of the usernames I the code behind I only can get the content of the Label so I don't know which Account it is exactly.
Sure i can make a loop to check `liste[i].Username = this.content`
But my Problem then is that i have more accounts and for example I have 2 accounts one facebook and one google but they have the same username how do I know now in the codebehind which account it is where I clicked

A friend said to me that I should try it with databinding but i´m new to coding so I don't know really how to do it or if this works with databinding.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do that is setting the Tag property of your label:

```
l.Tag = liste[i];
```

Then, you can get your user back in the subscribed method:

```
var myUser = (User)((Label)sender).Tag;
```

But your friend is right: Data binding is a much better way. In fact, in most cases, you shouldn't have any code in the code behind file (other than the automatically generated code). Try looking for MVVM on your favorite search engine.